# How to pass password automatically for rsync SSH command?

Tags: ssh, passwords, rsync

I need to do `rsync` by `ssh` and want to do it automatically without the need of passing password for `ssh` manually.

Comment: the easiest way to pypass password prompt every time you transfer or login your ssh is to create a key, here's how you can do that in 2 steps https://www.brightery.com/en/post/If-you-tired-of-writing-your-password-every-time-you-login-your-SSH

Comment: Also, just to add, if you reason you don't want to prompt for password is because you need to rsync many files, the the better solution is to store all the files in a txt list and just pass the option `--files-from=` that way it will only prompt once

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You should use a keyfile without passphrase for scripted ssh logins. This is obviously a security risk, take care that the keyfile itself is adequately secured.

From [Instructions for setting up passwordless ssh access](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/):

1. Run `ssh-keygen`
   It will ask for a path to the key file, a passphrase, and a repeat of the same passphrase. Answer all three by just pressing `Enter` (accepting the defaults).
2. Run `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <remote-host>`
   The path `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the public key file may be different if you chose another path in step 1. Replace `<remote-host>` with the IP or hostname of the remote host you want to log in to.
3. Run `ssh <remote-host>`
   The remote host should not ask for a password, and you should be logged in to the remote host.

Comment: There are no possibility for putting password in a text of command?

Comment: Not easily, there is no options for it in ssh

Comment: It should be noted that this is not always possible to do (e.g. many android ssh server implementation are quite limited).

Comment: @Ponkadoodle The OP is about client-side requests, not server-side. `ssh -i` should always be possible on the client side. Do you mean that the server may not support all key-types (e.g. ECDSA)? That would not be a major issue though, just a case of using `ssh-keygen -t`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Although this might appear to be a hassle at first, this is the correct answer. Passwords are sensitive information, and these should not be stored in clear, or used carelessly in programs. That is what keyfiles are for; just learn about [identity files, `rsync -e` and `ssh -i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127355/45354).

Comment: @MadScientist My only problem with this solution is that the rsync parts of the answer are buried in comments and none of them provide rigorous syntax or examples.  The basic ssh part of this tutorial you link to is fine, however.

Comment: Where is the manual / code example? If the external link is dead this answer is useless.

Comment: Some hosts ban key authentication, so password is the only option.

Comment: This did the job for me, Thanks for sharing !

Answer (score 132):

Use "sshpass" non-interactive ssh password provider utility

On Ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Command to rsync

```
 /usr/bin/rsync -ratlz --rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l username" src_path  dest_path
```

Comment: I know this is not best practice, but I've got a NAS with a crippled SSHD that won't do key-based auth. This answer was the missing piece to my automated-backup puzzle. So +1 for the last-resort answer

Comment: If you can not use a keyfile, but do not want to include the password in the command, you can write it into a temporary file and include it like this: `sshpass -p\`cat .password\` ssh [...]`. Then protect your `.password` file by `chmod 400 .password` to make sure only your user can read it.

Comment: For completeness, in the case of ssh'ing to a remote server, the `src_path` ought to be server:path, like so: `server01.mydomain.local:/path/to/folder`

Comment: this is definitely the right answer! it allow you to do scripting without ssh magic, just scripting one. ;) Kudos @Rajendra

Comment: since `-a` switch on rsync includes `-rlptgoD`, you can shorten the command like this: `rsync -az ...`

Comment: And, to mention: rsync has to be installed on destination machine, if you want to sync from local to remote machine! See: [sshpass: Falied to run command: No such file or directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/837564/sshpass-failed-to-run-command-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: This answer on the Unix Stack Exchange is much more succinct: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111534/119644

Comment: For a password with weird characters: `sshpass -f~/.passfile` will help, preceded by placing the password in `~/.passfile`.

Comment: @sneaky you can even do it without `rsync` available on remote, if you mount the remote target folder locally with `sshfs`. It's not optimal, but it works.

Answer (score 43):

You can avoid the password prompt on `rsync` command by setting the environment variable `RSYNC_PASSWORD` to the password you want to use or using the `--password-file` option.

Comment: only works if the destination server has rsync daemon running

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't help unless using rsync daemon, Google landed me here and it was exactly what I needed. For me, I needed direct rsync to rsyncd, no ssh. I just used the password-file option, and worked perfectly for a script.

Comment: and how to exactly use this in the command? any sample command?

Comment: @y_159 Before the rsync: read -s -p "ssh password: " RSYNC_PASSWORD

Answer (score 31):

I got it to work like this:

```
sshpass -p "password" rsync -ae "ssh -p remote_port_ssh" /local_dir  remote_user@remote_host:/remote_dir
```

Comment: what would the `remote_port_ssh` be set to?  It looks like a placeholder for an actual value.

Comment: @MaxWilliams If your remote server SSH server runs on a different port (it should), you can change `remote_port_ssh`. If it runs on default port you can skip this part.

Comment: So do we have to replace `remote_port_ssh` by a value or leave it like this?

Comment: if server port is 22, then discard  it, else you can specify particular port

Answer (score 18):

If you can't use a public/private keys, you can use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn rsync SRC DEST
expect "password:"
send "PASS\n"
expect eof
if [catch wait] {
    puts "rsync failed"
    exit 1
}
exit 0
```

You will need to replace SRC and DEST with your normal rsync source and destination parameters, and replace PASS with your password. Just make sure this file is stored securely!

Comment: those commands arent available on my `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)`

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me:

```
SSHPASS='myPassword'
/usr/bin/rsync -a -r -p -o -g --progress --modify-window=1 --exclude /folderOne -s -u --rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root"  source-path  myDomain:dest-path  >&2
```

I had to install `sshpass`

Comment: -a already implies -rlptgoD and in general, it would be much more helpful to have a reduced command line here.

Answer (score 6):

Another interesting possibility:

1. generate RSA, or DSA key pair (as it was described)
2. put public key to host (as it was already described)
3. run:

```
rsync --partial --progress --rsh="ssh -i dsa_private_file" host_name@host:/home/me/d .
```

Note: *-i dsa_private_file* which is your RSA/DSA private key

Basically, this approach is very similar to the one described by @Mad Scientist, however you do not have to copy your private key to ~/.ssh. In other words, it is useful for ad-hoc tasks (one time passwordless access)

Answer (score 6):

The official solution (and others) were incomplete when I first visited, so I came back, years later, to post this alternate approach in case any others wound up here intending to use a public/private key-pair:

Execute this from the target backup machine, which pulls from source to target backup

`rsync -av --delete -e 'ssh -p 59333 -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' user@10.9.9.3:/home/user/Server/ /home/keith/Server/`

Execute this from the source machine, which sends from source to target backup

`rsync -av --delete -e 'ssh -p 59333 -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' /home/user/Server/ user@10.9.9.3:/home/user/Server/`

And, if you are not using an alternate port for ssh, then consider the more elegant examples below:

Execute this from the target backup machine, which pulls from source to target backup:

`sudo rsync -avi --delete  user@10.9.9.3:/var/www/ /media/sdb1/backups/www/`

Execute this from the source machine, which sends from source to target backup:

`sudo rsync -avi --delete /media/sdb1/backups/www/ user@10.9.9.3:/var/www/`

If you are still getting prompted for a password, then you need to check your ssh configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and verify that the users in source and target each have the others' respective public ssh key by sending each over with `ssh-copy-id user@10.9.9.3`.

(Again, this is for using ssh key-pairs without a password, as an alternate approach, and ***not*** for passing the password over via a file.)

Comment: And an important side note is that in the alternate port example, you are directing ssh to your private key file, and when it executes the command on target, it will authenticate against its public key.

Comment: If the name of the user account on the remote system is not the same, add `-l <username>` to the ssh command.  eg `-e "ssh -i /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa -l john"`.  Thus you don't need the `user@` prefix on the paths.

Answer (score 5):

Use a ssh key.

Look at `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`.

After that you can use an `rsync` this way :

```
rsync -a --stats --progress --delete /home/path server:path
```

Comment: If I use key with ssh I write: ssh u@serv -i ./rsa
But how to do it in rsync?

Comment: If you put the key into your .ssh directory and give it a standard name (typically id_rsa / id_rsa.pub) it will be picked up automatically by rsync.

Answer (score 4):

Automatically entering the password for the rsync command is difficult. My simple solution to avoid the problem is to mount the folder to be backed up. Then use a local rsync command to backup the mounted folder.

```
mount -t cifs //server/source/ /mnt/source-tmp -o username=Username,password=password
rsync -a /mnt/source-tmp /media/destination/
umount /mnt/source-tmp
```

Comment: Do not use rsync with a mounted folder. All advantages rsync has are void then.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a secure solution using a gpg encrypted password.

1.Create a .secret file containing your password in the same folder as your rsync script using the command:

```
echo 'my-very-secure-password' > .secret
```

Note that the file is hidden by default for extra security.

2.Encrypt your password file using the following gpg command and follow the prompts:

```
gpg -c .secret
```

This will create another file named .secret.gpg. Your password is now encrypted.

3.Delete the plain text password file

```
rm .secret
```

4.Finally in your rsync script use gpg and sshpass as follows:

```
gpg -dq secret.gpg | sshpass rsync -avl --mkpath /home/john user_name@x.x.x.x/home
```

The example is syncing the entire home folder for the user named john to a remote server with IP x.x.x.x

Comment: That's actually a quite clever solution! (Sadly, in my case, I cannot use `sshpass`, but I _do_ have `gpg` on both client and server).

Answer (score 2):

Though you've already implemented it by now,

you can also use any [expect](http://debaan.blogspot.com/2007/09/simple-expect-ssh-example.html) implementation (you'll find alternatives in Perl, Python: pexpect, paramiko, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

I use a VBScript file for doing this on Windows platform, it servers me very well.

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"rsync -a Name@192.168.1.100:/Users/Name/Projects/test ."
WScript.Sleep 100
shell.SendKeys"Your_Password"
shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Exposing a password in a command is not safe, especially when using a bash script, if you tried to work with keyfiles thats will be nice.
create keys in your host with `ssh-keygen` and copy the public key with `ssh-copy-id "user@hostname.example.com` and then use rsync addin the option `-e "ssh -i  $HOME/.ssh/(your private key)"` to force rsync using ssh connection via the the private key that you create earlier.

example :

`rsync -avh --exclude '$LOGS' -e "ssh -i  $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" --ignore-existing $BACKUP_DIR  $DESTINATION_HOST:$DESTINATION_DIR;`

Comment: Exposing a password in a command is neither safe nor unsafe.

Answer (score -1):

Following the idea posted by Andrew Seaford, this is done using sshfs:

```
echo "SuperHardToGuessPass:P" | sshfs -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com:/mypath/ /mnt/source-tmp/ -o workaround=rename -o password_stdin
rsync -a /mnt/source-tmp/ /media/destination/
umount /mnt/source-tmp
```