# RSync works stand alone, not as script in Sublime Text Build System

Tags: bash, build, cygwin, sublimetext2, rsync

This is my script, it [uses expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299951/how-to-pass-password-for-rsync-ssh-command) to fill out the password field for rsync, and this is the only way I got it to work with a variable ($FILE, suggestions are welcomed).

It works in cmd, output is as expected (-P switch outputs progressbar, so I know it works without checking).

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/cygdrive/c/"
FILE=$(cygpath -u $1); #full file path to sync
a='USER@HOST:/; expect "*?assword:*" {send "user_pass\r";interact};'
LINE="spawn rsync -P --port=port $FILE "$a 
expect -c "$LINE"
```

This is my Sublime Text build sys in the .sublime-project file (I have included cygwin/bin in my path, so it recognizes bash.).

```
{
    "name" : "RSync This",
    "shell":  true,
    "cmd": ["bash","/cygdrive/c/rsync.sh","$file"]            
}
```

Outputs:

```
spawn rsync -P --port=22 /cygdrive/c/test USER@HOST:/
USER@HOST's password: [Finished in 0.8s]
```

No progressbar, no changes. Can't figure out what gives.

Any suggestions where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The Sublime Text console/build system is not interactive, so there is unfortunately no way to enter input during a build. To get around this, you'll either need some other way of authenticating, such as with an SSH key, or you'll need to program a small [plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) that uses `sublime.Window.show_input_panel()` to obtain the password from the user.